# Vertical scrollbar for rows in group

Tags: ag-grid

Is is possible to have a vertical scrollbar for rows inside a group, e.g Group 1 will have 10 rows, but I would like to show max 5 rows (with scrollbar, to scroll to rows 6-10).

```
-> Group 1
  - Row 1
  - Row 2
  - Row 3
  - Row 4
  - Row 5
-> Group 2
-> Group 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is feasible with master-detail pattern.

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    masterDetail: true,
    detailCellRendererParams: {
        detailGridOptions: {
            columnDefs :[...]
            ...
            // all detail gridOptions go here
        },
        getDetailRowData: function(params) {
            params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
        }
    }
};
```

To get handler of detail grid

```
// lookup a specific DetailGridInfo by id
var detailGridInfo = masterGridOptions.api.getDetailGridInfo('someDetailGridId');
```

Note: This is avilable from ag-Grid v14.2 onwards in Enterprise version only.

[Read more here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/)